# Plotting XML/CSV Data in ASP.NET Charts (in VS2008 using VB code)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, csv, charts, highcharts

What I intend to do is to:

1. Retrieve data from a CSV file
2. Add those data point by point into ASP.NET chart

I am trying to use CHART.DataBindTable and it isn't working

```
    Dim 2014_BoilerPressureTable As String = "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\BOILER_Folder\Jan2014.csv"

   Dim PressureTable As DataTable = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(2014_BoilerPressureTable)


    Chart1.DataSource = PressureTable

    Chart1.Series("Series 1").XValueMember = "Time"
    Chart1.Series("Series 1").YValueMembers = "Pressure"


    Chart1.DataBind()
```

The CSV File only contains two columns: 1. DATE and TIME 2. PRESSURE (in double format)

Whenever I try this code, the chart area won't plot and an error occurs:
A chart element with the name 'Series 1' could not be found in the 'SeriesCollection'.

Please help. Even references and suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason why my code wasn't working is because I did not add "Series 1" in the series collection before adding the X and Y Values.

I just modified the code a little and voila,

```
Chart1.Series.Add("Series 1")
Chart1.Series("Series 1").XValueMember = "Time"
Chart1.Series("Series 1").YValueMembers = "Pressure"

Chart1.DataSource = PressureTable
Chart1.DataBind()
```